# Is there a mirror site for elementary os?

Tags: system-installation, download, iso

Is there a mirror site for elementary OS .iso image file?

I tried to download elementary OS .iso installation image file but it was too slow. So I wonder if there is a mirror site near me for elementary OS. I searched the web but couldn't find one.

Can anyone please help me find a mirror site? Thanks a lot.

Note that I do not want to use tools like Motrix(based on aria2) to speed up the download because it is considered as not safe enough.

It would be better if elementary OS could have mirror sites around the world just like other successful Linux versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There no *verified* mirrors for the ISO files, but you can download the image via the BitTorrent protocol using the Magnet link:

[image: Click the U]

Simply click on the “U”, and this will open the appropriate application, connect you to several peers with relatively good upload speeds.

After downloading, be sure to [verify your download](https://elementary.io/docs/installation#verify-your-download). So long as everything is good, you should see the following:

```
SHA256 hash of Downloads\elementaryos-6.0-stable.20210831.iso:
60bbaca60d8dbf9f5f112ade2ee5924af976ba01ce19e53e871c8deced7ae884
```

Comment: Thank you a lot. It works!